# Jquery - If greater than certain amount of px load this else load nothing and vice versa?

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a script that checks browser resolution at 1200px.

If the resolution is greater than 1200px it loads the slideshow code, but if it's less then 1200px resolution it does not load the code and then the CSS I have assigns a static background image.

The issue I'm seeing, is if you load first less than 1200px you get the static image as wanted and then if you expand the window size above 1200px you get the slideshow also what I wanted, but if I go back below 1200px the slideshow continues to function. Is there a way to go back and forth loading and then unloading the slideshow code?

I'm thinking that someone with a tablet for example first views the site tall view first and then flips to landscape view and then flips back to tall view. When they flip back to tall view the slideshow would still be running. I hope this makes sense.

Here is the jquery code I'm using, if anyone can help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var $window = $(window).on('load resize', function(){
            // Notice I've combined load and resize because I need this to work on load/refresh as well as on resize.
            var width = $window.width();

                if (width >= 1200) {
                    // If resolution is greater than or equal to 1200px it loads this code... 
                    $("body").vegas({
                            delay: 10000,
                            shuffle: true,
                            transition: 'zoomOut',
                            transitionDuration: 7000,
                            animation: 'random',
                            timer: false,
                            slides: [
                                { src: "img/slides/001.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/002.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/003.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/004.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/005.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/006.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/007.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/008.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/009.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/010.jpg" },
                                { src: "img/slides/011.jpg" }
                            ]
                        });
                } else if (width < 1200) {
                        // Else, nothing is loaded and a static image is set using CSS...
                        // Works when going from less than 1200 to more than 1200, but not vice versa.
                        // How do fix?
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: what have you tried so far in terms of disabling the slider after the resize?

Comment: See documentation http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/ `$("body").on("vegaspause", function (e, index, slideSettings) {
    // remove slide images , set static image
});` , `else if (width < 1200) {
                      
                        $("body").trigger("vegaspause")
                }` ?

Comment: Hi guest271314, I'm not sure I'm following your suggestion. I'm rather new to this, I have looked over all the settings, but nothing is standing out to me. Could you explain your solution a bit more maybe show me how to apply your solution to the code I provided so it's more clear to me, thanks.

Comment: @JeremyBrown Not tried `.vegas()` , though appear can attach `"vagaspause"` event to `$("body")` element ? , call `$("body").trigger("vegaspause")` to trigger event , reset static image within event handler ?

Comment: I think vegaspause is only used to pause the slideshow. Again new to this, played around with your recommendation but nothing changed or I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7egouvzf/1/ try this.

Comment: Guess what? It works perfectly! Thank you so much! I'd give you a 1 up, but according to this site I'm too much of a newb ;) As to not take credit away from you, you should post this as an answer or update your answer with this code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` for getting current values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        var width = $(this).width();
 //---------------- ^^^^^^^ --------------
        if (width >= 1200) {
            $("body").vegas({
                delay: 10000,
                shuffle: true,
                transition: 'zoomOut',
                transitionDuration: 7000,
                animation: 'random',
                timer: false,
                slides: [
                    {src: "img/slides/001.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/002.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/003.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/004.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/005.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/006.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/007.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/008.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/009.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/010.jpg"}, 
                    {src: "img/slides/011.jpg"}
                ]
            });
        } else if (width < 1200) {
            /*...*/
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work. Same issue persists. Load lower than 1200px and static image, increase resolution past 1200 slideshow loads but when I decrease it back down lower than 1200 slideshow is still going. I also tested on my tablet and tall view, static image, when I flip my device slideshow starts, flip it back to tall and slideshow is still playing, so what I'm trying to do is when I flip it back to stop the slide show.

Comment: @JeremyBrown did you try `$("body").trigger("vegaspause")` in else if condition?

Comment: yes I added that, but nothing happens when I resize the window under 1200px.  `} else if (width < 1200) { $("body").trigger("vegaspause") }` I should say nothing happens when size it above 1200 and then try to go back to under 1200.

Comment: Maybe if when the screen resolution goes under 1200px it could refresh the browser? So if it loads below 1200px initially, no refresh, but if the window is resized after going over 1200px and then back down below 1200px it refreshes? Not sure how good that would be, but it might work, any ideas?

Comment: @JeremyBrown refreshing window is not a standard way. we can figure out something better.